# Nginx unmet dependencies, unable to upgrade / remove

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, newrelic

Recently I had installed newrelic on my Ubuntu server and after that I automatically started getting errors in log with failed to load newrelic extension.

I tried upgrading / removing newrelic but in both cases I am getting a error:

```
ubuntu@ip:/etc/php$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nginx : Depends: nginx-core (< 1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.4.1~) but 1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 is installed or
                  nginx-full (< 1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.4.1~) but it is not installed or
                  nginx-light (< 1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.4.1~) but it is not installed or
                  nginx-extras (< 1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.4.1~) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

I tried running `sudo apt-get -f install` but it results in output:

```
ubuntu@ip:/etc/php$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-78 linux-headers-4.4.0-78-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-79 linux-headers-4.4.0-79-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-78-generic linux-image-4.4.0-79-generic nginx-common nginx-core
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  nginx
The following packages will be upgraded:
  nginx
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
7 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 787 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,777 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  nginx
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] y
Get:1 http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu xenial/nginx amd64 nginx amd64 1.12.1-1~xenial [787 kB]
Fetched 787 kB in 2s (275 kB/s)
(Reading database ... 138963 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nginx_1.12.1-1~xenial_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nginx (1.12.1-1~xenial) over (1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.4) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nginx_1.12.1-1~xenial_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/etc/nginx/uwsgi_params', which is also in package nginx-common 1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nginx_1.12.1-1~xenial_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I did find [one article](https://askubuntu.com/questions/243568/nginx-dependency-problem-trying-to-upgrade) which suggests removing nginx and then reinstalling. This is a production server with continuous traffic so I want to avoid risk of uninstalling nginx, and then later failing. I have changed configs of nginx, and don't have note of all my changes. Any safe way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching and experimenting with lot of stuff, I could not find any solution and finally followed this https://askubuntu.com/questions/243568/nginx-dependency-problem-trying-to-upgrade

I did following:

1. I made a backup of `/etc/nginx`
2. Then removed nginx
3. re-installed nginx
4. Then as it is replaced `/etc/nginx` with backup folder and it started working

I had a downtime of around 15-20 mins doing all this.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by passing force-overwrite to the underlying dpkg process.  This is the command I used:

```
sudo apt -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" upgrade nginx
```

Source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/56761/force-apt-get-to-overwrite-file-installed-by-another-package

Comment: I tried this but it is not working. But I am getting same unmet dependency error.

Answer (score -1):

1. Run `apt list --upgradable` first.
2. Next run `sudo apt-get install <package-name>` starting with the package at the top of the list.
3. Run `apt list --upgradable` again to check if all the packages have been installed. If not, repeat steps 1 and 2.